# Dividing a table into 2 but not aligned

Tags: html, html-table

So Ive created a table to divide the html text into 2 languages English/Spanish, but for some reason which I can not understand, the text is starting just below for the second column... Like this:

[image: Should be up!]

Maybe I am missing an atribute? Or some justification?

```html
<table width="863">
  <tr>
    <td width="428">
      <p>
        <strong>AVISO DE PRIVACIDAD</strong>
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>ESTUDIANES Y PADRES DE FAMILIA</strong>
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;<strong>Identidad y domicilio del Responsable:</strong>
      </p>
      <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT.</p>
      <p>&nbsp;<strong>TEXT TEXT:</strong>
      </p>
      <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
      <p>....</p>

    </td>
    <td width="435">
      <p>
        <strong>PRIVACY NOTICE</strong>
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>STUDENTS AND PARENTS</strong>
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;<strong>Identity and address of the Responsible Party:</strong>
      </p>
      <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
      <p>&nbsp;<strong>Categories of the data treated by the School:</strong>
      </p>
      <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
      <p>&nbsp;a)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <u>TEXT TEXT
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You can see from the snippet demo that the problem must be due to something we can't see here. I would suggest that this is a misuse of a table anyway and a more modern layout might be better. Consider CSS grid or flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely fine as there is no margin or padding. It could be because of

- the editor you are using
- some css file which is messing with body/table/p/... tags

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers! I just found a "forced" solution. Just added valign="top" into the td as an atribute.